# query to retrieve all translations and nodes of a language that has been removed from the system?

Tags: database, i18n-l10n

I am experiencing an issue after a language has been removed from the system. Every time I go on the admin/content page on a drupal 8 site I get:

```
Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay->buildMultiple() (line 254 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity/EntityViewDisplay.php).
```

This is a known issue on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2851029) but it has not been addressed yet.
I am afraid this may be a recurring issue and I am trying to build something to clean up content causing the issue (i.e. the content language was removed from the system).

I am looking for a Drupal query that would return all the nodes(entities)/translations which has a language that has been deleted from the system. I can load all content and loop through them to check `$entity->language() == FALSE` or `$entity->language() == NULL` but that does not seem to be performant even with using the batch API. Ideally, db query that returns the IDs of the offending content would be much better.
Then I could update them to language neutral or delete the content.

I am wrote something that does something similar to the way node update translations after a language is deleted:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function clearRevisionsLanguage(LanguageInterface $language) {
    return $this->database->update('node_revision')
      ->fields(['langcode' => LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED])
      ->condition('langcode', $language->getId())
      ->execute();
  }
```

I repurposed the above to:

```
function some_helper_to_update_node_lang($lang_code) {
  \Drupal::database()->update('node_revision')
    ->fields(['langcode' => LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED])
    ->condition('langcode', $lang_code)
    ->execute();
}
```

But the above function requires the language code, which is reasonable but I am not sure how to make this a more flexible in as much to return all content that has a removed language.

Answer (score 2):

I ended executing this function to clean up the content:

```
function delete_non_existing_language_content() {
  // 1. Get enabled languages
  $languages = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();
  $lang_codes = array();
  foreach ($languages as $language) {
    $lang_codes[] = $language->getId();
  } 
  // 2. Get all the nodes that have langcode not in the language list.  
  $result = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data')
    ->fields('node_field_data')
    ->condition('langcode', $lang_codes, 'NOT IN')
    ->execute();

  // @todo think I can use fetchAllKeyed instead?
  $nids = array_keys($result->fetchAllAssoc('nid'));

  // 3.Delete all of them:
  // @todo Or possibly update them to language neutral code if possible:
  $storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $entities = $storage_handler->loadMultiple($nids);
  $storage_handler->delete($entities);

}
```

This worked for my use case, but I don't think it will be performant for large databases.